# Passing an object to a function taking pointer as parameter

Tags: c++, pointers, function, reference

How does it work when I only have an object but my function takes a pointer to that type of object.

```
Someoclass test1;

SomeFunction( Someclass*)
{
    //does something
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pass the address of the object.

```
SomeFunction(&test1);
```

Comment: & is used for 2 things, references and addresses ?

Comment: @Apoc: '&' has 3 meanings: <var> `&` <var> is the **bitwise and** operator, <type>`&` is a **reference** type, `&`<var> is the **address of** operator

Answer (score 0):

To call the function, you need to use the address of operator (&). So in your case:

```
Someclass test1;

SomeFunction(&test1);
```

If you are asking how pointers work, [there's a detailed explanation here](http://augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/ptr.html).